# Reg : Building CorDApp for a particular CordaVersion=4.x

Tags: corda

Is it possible to build an example, lets say IOUExample for a specific version of corda ?
because in the samples, ( https://github.com/corda/samples) , the constants.properties (https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/constants.properties) says --> cordaVersion= **4.0**   ***So how do I build it from 4.1 or a 4.2 ?***

Comment: Q: Does it really matter what some properties file in some samples code subfolder says?

Comment: These are not just some properties in some examples code - they are officially published in the r3 github repository. And r3 documentation do talk about this at length. Also lot of documentation going into what goes into 4.1 and 4.2. But not a word which says how to make sure that your application is built on 4.1 or 4.1 and not 4.0. So answer is Yes.

Comment: Q: Have you actually tried compiling and running any of the GitHub examples against a CorDapp 4.1.x or 4.2.x kernel?  If you got any errors, please add them to your post.  Q: What specific version of Corda/Corda Enterprise are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP's question (why don't the authors of the GitHub sample code update the Corda version?) can't really be answered on SO.  He either needs to 1) give a specific error message using the old version, 2) hack the sample code to the new veresion and give an error message if it fails, and 3) in either case, ask the folks who provided the sample code in the first place.

Comment: Okay @paulsm4, I will remove the question which can't be answered in SO. But the other part stays.

Comment: My question is pretty simple. How do one compile a CorDapp against corda 4.1 or 4.2 and tell specifically that it's completely and correctly compiled against Corda 4.1 and 4.2? I don't see that listed in docs.corda.net. Do you have that information?  how does it matter it errors or not. We should be able to tell what to give as $corda release version in the Gradle build file. Corda encourages us to post these questions in this channel.

Comment: OK: suggestions: 1) Join the [corda-dev](https://groups.io/g/corda-dev) mailing list and post your question there. In this case, you're likelier to get a knowledgeable answer, and get it faster.  2) Reach out to [Peter Li](https://www.linkedin.com/in/peter-yingxi-li/) directly. He's the R3 developer who posted to GitHub, he might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corda_release_version and corda_release_group controls which version of Corda jar you are using.

If you look here(https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V4/build.gradle), this one uses Corda 4.1

But we suggest any CorDapp should be developed on the last version of Corda.